# How to get correct legend labels on a Google visualization donut chart

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization, pie-chart

I'm drawing a pie chart with only 2 segments, one segment colored red and the other colored blue.  The chart draws correctly but segment colors and the legend use the wrong colors. On the attached screenshot, the blue segment should be red and be labelled Overdue in the legend and the red segment should be blue and labelled Protocol in the legend.  The numbers displayed in the segmenats are correct, it's just the colors that are switched.

[image]

Here's the code that builds the chart data and assigns the colors.

```
chartData[0] = ['Status', 'Count', {role: 'style'}]
chartData[1]= ['Overdue',1012,"red"]
chartData[2]= ['Protocol',980,"#BDC667"]
var datatable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);
```

The chart options are:

```
var options = {
    title: 'Installed Curtains By Status',
    pieSliceText: 'value',
    chartArea: {
        width: '95%',
    },
    animation: {
        startup: true,
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'out',
    },
    legend: {position: "right"}
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the style role is not supported by `PieChart`
what is shown are the default colors.
instead, use the `colors` configuration option.

```
var options = {
  title: 'Installed Curtains By Status',
  pieSliceText: 'value',
  chartArea: {
    width: '95%',
  },
  colors: ["red", "#BDC667"],
  animation: {
    startup: true,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'out',
  },
  legend: {position: "right"}
};
```

check the chart's [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#data-format) for role availability...

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.